# How do I get a five-star overall rating for a match?

Tags: pokken-tournament

After a match in Pokkén Tournament is concluded, the player is given star rankings in four categories - Offense, Defense, Technique, and Bonus - followed by an overall rating based on those four. Getting five-star matches is required to unlock certain titles.

These stars seem fairly inconsistent, though. I've had Perfect wins (no damage taken) that only gave 2.5 stars for Offense and Defense, for instance, and I can't even tell what Technique is based off of. Landing a KO with a Synergy Burst attack seems to help Bonus but doesn't necessarily influence the others.

What are these ratings based on, and how can I reliably approach getting 5-Star matches?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the more stats you have in it, the better you will do, offence can be boosted through use of combos, as with technique. for defence and bonus im not sure. But i do know that my level 95 weavile gets 5 star matches 90% of the time, so it could be a level thing.